# Where to place an XML file containing data within an Android app

Tags: android, resources

I am new to Android development.  I have an XML file with data that the app will read.  Where should I keep this XML file?  Should it be stored within the "value" folder?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd say that depends. What do you save in your XML-File? There also is a `res/xml`-folder, where XML-Files can be kept. But Android does nearly anything with XML-Files, so you might want to read my [little Tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228215-working-with-resourses/) about where to put which recourses.

Also, there is a difference between the `assets` and the `res`-directory's:

### res

- No subdirectorys are allowed under
  the specific resource-folders.
- The `R`-class indexes all resources
  and provides simple access.
- There are some simple methods which
  help reading files stored in the
  `res`-directory

### assets

- Subdirectorys are allowed (as much as
  you like).
- No indexing by the `R`-class
- Reading resources stored in `assets`
  is done using the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Comment: This is the correct answer. I prefer no use assets directory and then use Simple XML to do my XML parsing: http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between the two. It helps.

Comment: res/xml folder helped me. I had an xml data file with custom tags.

Answer (score 5):

You can put it in the res/raw folder.  Then you will access it using:

```
getResources().openRawResource(resourceName)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement and after lot of research , I found 2 solution to  place a custom XML  :
You can place custom XML in

1. res/raw/
2. res/xml/

To access these location you will use following code :

a. if XML is placed in res/raw then :

***getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.custom-xml)*** :

This gives you easy methods for reading xml :

with below code I am reading XML in memory placed in raw folder :

---

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.custom-xml)));
            
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
    str.append(line);
}
```

2nd Option :

**getResources().getxml(R.xml.custom-xml);**

with this you could read the xml using eventbased parser.

Comment: correction  ** getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.custom-xml) This  should be getResources().getxml(R.xml.custom-xml)