# Where to store simple data files (xml formatted) in android app?

Tags: android, xml, sax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where to place an xml file with data in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051280/where-to-place-an-xml-file-with-data-in-app)

I'm kinda new to android dev. I'm storing the data related to my app in an XML file. I'm trying to use SAX parser to read/write/edit data to that xml file.

Where is the proper place to store this xml file? In assets/res/some-other folder ? (I want to use internal memory)

Is there any problem with saving app data to internal memory? This app won't have huge amounts of data. I need to read/ write/ modify this xml file depending on user actions. (I read that we can't edit files in assests at runtime !!)

Given a particular directory, how can I access it using InputStream in order to feed it to SAX XMLReader?

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051518/1196437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want also to write the file, I don't think that you can do that in /res or /assets. Take a look at the android data storage options. For example, you can write the XML file to the internal storage.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thanks. Isn't res/xml or assets folder considered as internal data storage ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store your xml files in assets.
But I suggest you to create a folder name XML in /res/. It'll help you to easily use it with id "R.xml.xml_file".

Comment: Thanks. I found that using res/xml folder has some problem with SAX parser. I got an exception like- org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token). But when I changed the file to res/raw folder it worked strangely. This doesn't make sense but it saves a lot of time. The code I used was..

InputStream fstream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);

I passed this InputStream to XMLReader of SAX implmentation. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yah It'll definitely help others.

Answer (score 1):

Though it depends on entirely your requirements, I would suggest better to create a directory using [getDir(String dirName, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and store your xmls here.

Above can be used to store the data dynamically means when application is running. But if your application is already having xml files, its better to store it in asset folder because you can create sub directories easily here.

Comment: Thanks. I will have only one xml file. I have to read/ write/ edit that file. Any suggestions which option is better & easy to deal with 1) res/sub-folder 2) assests 3) some other directory as U said ??

Comment: I would suggest the following procedure:
1. Place your xml in asset folder
2. After compilation and uploading your apk in device/emulator and while running first time, copy this xml from asset to directory specific to your application using getDir method and start reading/writing the same.